# org mode refile error

Tags: emacs, org-mode, bookmarks

Since some time (but I didn't change anything in .emacs), I have some errors with emacs's behaviour :

- Remember mode will not kill the temporary buffer on "Ctl-C Ctl-C"
- Orgmode will not refile any entry

Both operations complain with error "Not bookmark format"

I restored an old .emacs to make sure that I didn't mess it up but the error persists.

Where can I investigate to find out the problem ?

I have Emacs 24.2.1 since end of august.

The built in orgmode version is 7.8.11 (I see 7.9.2 is out ...)

Comment: The error comes from the [bookmark.el code](http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/bookmark.el).
I don't know any lisp, so I don't feel like getting in orgmode source code to understand why this error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug to the emacs team and they found out that the error comes from a corrupted bookmark file.

I removed my ~/.emacs.d/bookmark file (it was empty) and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

It's always best to start debugging problems such as this by seeing if the problem still happens when you ignore your init file altogether - try starting emacs with `--no-init-file` and seeing if you still get the problem. If you don't then it's clearly *something* in your init file.

You can also get odd behaviour if you've got a local install of Org-mode in addition to the one bundled with Emacs itself - eg if you pull in a newer one through ELPA. If you have a local install through ELPA then you can try uninstalling the Org-mode package and trying again using the built-in Org-mode.

I have something similar to the following in my init file to make it switch to the ELPA-installed Org-mode to avoid such problems (this variant is untested so forgive me if it's not quite right):

```
(package-initialize)  ; load and initialise ELPA-installed packages
(org-reload)          ; restart Org-mode with the ELPA package
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have no ELPA package on my system (or do I ?) nor any exotic package for emacs.
Running emacs with `--no-init-file` is a good idea : orgmode still complains on refile. I'm investigating now and will report back here.